# dstat fails to start...trying to load python3's csv?

Tags: debian, python

i'm on Debian unstable and `apt-get dist-upgrade` every couple weeks. it seems something happened that breaks dstat (only when trying to output to csv). dstat is Python2-based, but the error somehow appears inside of Python3's csv lib? anyone know how this can happen? is it some include path that got mis-symlinked?

i'm running this:

```
dstat -Tcndm --nocolor --noheaders --output /var/log/dstat.csv &
```

the error:

```
Dec 28 22:36:37 localhost rc.local[879]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Dec 28 22:36:37 localhost rc.local[879]:   File "/usr/bin/dstat", line 2847, in <module>
Dec 28 22:36:37 localhost rc.local[879]:     main()
Dec 28 22:36:37 localhost rc.local[879]:   File "/usr/bin/dstat", line 2687, in main
Dec 28 22:36:37 localhost rc.local[879]:     scheduler.run()
Dec 28 22:36:37 localhost rc.local[879]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/sched.py", line 151, in run
Dec 28 22:36:37 localhost rc.local[879]:     action(*argument, **kwargs)
Dec 28 22:36:37 localhost rc.local[879]:   File "/usr/bin/dstat", line 2806, in perform
Dec 28 22:36:37 localhost rc.local[879]:     oline = oline + o.showcsv() + o.showcsvend(totlist, vislist)
Dec 28 22:36:37 localhost rc.local[879]:   File "/usr/bin/dstat", line 547, in showcsv
Dec 28 22:36:37 localhost rc.local[879]:     if isinstance(self.val[name], types.ListType) or isinstance(self.val[name], types.TupleType):
Dec 28 22:36:37 localhost rc.local[879]: NameError: name 'types' is not defined
```

thanks!

Comment: Note that dstat has been abandoned by its author and replaced by dool, which for some reason is not yet packaged in Debian. The dstat in Debian appears to be Red Hat's hostile takeover of the original dstat.

Answer (score 1):

ok, figured it out. had to change the type-checking on lines 547 & 552:

before:

```
if isinstance(self.val[name], types.ListType) or isinstance(self.val[name], types.TupleType):
    for j, val in enumerate(self.val[name]):
        line = line + printcsv(val)
        if j + 1 != len(self.val[name]):
            line = line + char['sep']
elif isinstance(self.val[name], types.StringType):
```

after:

```
if isinstance(self.val[name], (tuple, list)):
    for j, val in enumerate(self.val[name]):
        line = line + printcsv(val)
        if j + 1 != len(self.val[name]):
            line = line + char['sep']
elif isinstance(self.val[name], str):
```